# Two element combinations of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

If i have an array of letters, for example

`['A','C','D','E']`

and I wanted to find all the 2 letter combinations of this array, what is the best way of doing this without using 2 for loops. For example:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
  for (var j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++) {
    console.log(arr[i] + " " + arr[j]);
  }
}
```

The issue with this, is that if the array becomes massive (1000 elements), it usually times out. Is there another way (alternate data structure etc to do this)?

Comment: That would be permutations in an array, and there are several answers showing how to do that, but you'd have to iterate, probably more than once.

Comment: There is a general form algo for n choose k but its not more efficient in terms of time complexity than your code. 1000 choose 2 is always going to equal the same number so there is no optimization you can do in this area. Maybe you should reconsider if you need every combination to solve your problem?

Comment: The main reason Ive asked this as well is because on Hackerrank, my algorithm usually passes the first few tests, but when numbers get too large or arrays are too large... javascript times out. Even for a very simple algorithm....

Comment: Show us the problem! Simple doesnt mean faster

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.map()`

Something like this

```js
var arr = ['A','C','D','E'],
    combinations = arr.map((v,i)=>arr.slice(i+1).map(v2=>v+v2));

console.log(combinations);
```

---

Although this code will also iterate twice over the elements. 
(*it will actually perform worse than your code since `map` executes a function for each item and it also creates temporary array copies with the `slice`, so it is here just for an alternate approach, not a more performant.*)

Comment: Thanks! One more question, what if we want completely unique, for example AC === CA, so we don't want to store CA?

Comment: @TylerEvans updated answer, and also added a note about performance.

Comment: I don't see how this is of any use!

Comment: If its less time efficient then how does using pretty syntax help OP? He said *his* code was timing out so this won't be any better. I notice there is sometimes a misconception among beginners that the more concise the syntax the faster the execution time which we all know isn't the case at all.

Comment: i mainly concentrated on the "not using two loops" part. I mention the performance issues and that this is a different approach in terms of coding tools available.

Comment: Yep, basically my question is - is there any way of doing this without using 2 loops (or using a function with uses 2 loops underlying)

Comment: Well in the question you said you were facing a timing out problem in your concluding statement so thats why I assumed that. Also this solution uses two loops they are just covered in sugar.

Answer (score 1):

I really beat this one into the ground. As expected, @Louis Durand 's answer of two nested for loops was fastest on an array containing 100 strings (around 4 ms on my machine). This shows that a nested loop is probably your best bet in this situation.

Second fastest is my recursive solution which did the same in around 7-8 ms.

Third was @Redu 's answer which clocked in around 12-15 ms for the same task. I suspect his implementation is slower because he uses slice method in his algo to update array (other answers just increment the index leaving the input array unchanged which is much faster). Also this implementation results in multiple copies of the input array being stored in memory (every time the function is called it creates a new input array from the original array from which  it removes the first elelment). This could also potentially affect performance.

So to answer your question: no I don't think there is a much better approach to what you are doing other than concatenating onto string and printing answers at the very end (what Louis suggested).

```js
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< 100; i++){
        arr.push(i+"");
      }
 /*
    console.time("test0");
    test0();

    function test0() {
    var s = "";
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++) {
      for (var j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++) {
        s += arr[i] + " " + arr[j]+" ; ";
      }
      s += "\n";
    }

    console.log(s);
    }
    console.timeEnd("test0"); 
*/
   
    console.time("test1"); 
    test1();
    function test1() {
    var output = [];
    getCombos(0, 0, [], 2);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(output));

     function getCombos(index, depth, tmp, k){
     if(depth < k){
         for(var i = index; i<arr.length; i++){
             var tmp1 =  [arr[i]];
             Array.prototype.push.apply(tmp1, tmp);
             getCombos(i+1, depth+1,tmp1, k);
           }
        }else{
             output.push(tmp);
          }
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd("test1");

        /*
        console.time("test2"); 
        test2();
        function test2(){
    Array.prototype.combinations = function(n){
      return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => (Array.prototype.push.apply(p,n > 1 ? a.slice(i+1).combinations(n-1).map(e => (e.push(c),e))
                                                                          : [[c]]),p),[]);

};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.combinations(2)));
    }

    console.timeEnd("test2");*/
```

Here is a recursive solution that doesn't solve your time complexity problem but is another way to consider.  The added advantage is that you can generalize it to any k so you are not stuck finding only combinations of two letters. Also you only declare one loop (although more than one copy of it will exist in your call stack)

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var output = "";
getCombos(0, 0, [], 2);
console.log(output);

 function getCombos(index, depth, tmp, k){
 if(depth < k){
     for(var i = index; i<arr.length; i++){
         var tmp1 =  [...tmp, arr[i]];
         getCombos(i+1, depth+1,tmp1, k);
       }
    }else{
         output += tmp.toString() + ";";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer?? oO Nice tests, sums up the other posts. Have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Not only two but with any number of elements you might do as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.combinations = function(n){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p.concat(n > 1 ? a.slice(i+1).combinations(n-1).map(e => [].concat(e,c))
                                                 : [[c]]),[]);
};

console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5,6].combinations(2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5,6].combinations(3)));
```

Well as per @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski's comments I have refactored my code to use `.push()` operations in the place of `.concat()` instructions and also where required a spread operation i did use `Array.prototype.push.apply(context,[args])`. These two changes made the code to run 2.5 ~ 3 times faster (resulting 3.5-7 msecs vs 9.5-19 msecs) when an input of 100 items array is given and a combination of two of each is requested. Yet once tried with 1000 items of 2 combinations the difference is more dramatic like 400ms vs 6000ms.

A test can be seen at https://repl.it/DyrU

```js
Array.prototype.combinations = function(n){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => (Array.prototype.push.apply(p,n > 1 ? a.slice(i+1).combinations(n-1).map(e => (e.push(c),e))
                                                                      : [[c]]),p),[]);
};

console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5,6].combinations(2)));
```

Comment: your solution is slow because you update input array with slice.

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski This is not a super performer but it's not because of `.slice()` which is an "extremely" efficient array method. What makes this code slow is the `.concat()` operation. A `.push()` with spread operator would do much better. I will look into that later.

Comment: I do something very similar in my solution (concat within one recursion and then push final output of nth recursive path to overall solution) and I get a faster result. I don't see how else you can explain it. Slice may be efficient but its still linear so there is definitely a cost when you continuosly call it. I guess you are adding a ton of copies of the array into memory which you don't really need so this could be another explanation.

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski I would like you to have another look at the refactored version of the code. Boosting this algo further would still be possible by replacing the Array functors with their imperative equivalents.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that using push instead of concat could give you such an edge! I implemented it in my algo and it still a couple times faster than yours. I'm not trying to brag about this I just want to point out that a FP approach seems difficult to implement here. The difference now has to come from splice.

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski Yes you are totally right. JS is not Haskell and FP part of it is still just a syntactical sugar over the core of it. But i have to say i love to think the functional way despite the cost of performance. :)

Comment: Yea agreed and I don't mean to bash FP obviously, I think its neat too and I try to use it when I can. Admittedly I'm not as experienced in it but I am learning a ton from reading answers like this. There are some problems where if I'm trying to think quickly I just mentally default to what I know best and it happened to be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has a mistake cause here, E would never be used.
It should rather be:

```
var s = "";
for (var i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++) {
  for (var j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++) {
    s += arr[i] + " " + arr[j]+" ; ";
  }
  s += "\n";
}
console.log(s);
```

Note that if you log everything in the console, it's no surprise that it times out.

Comment: Thanks, i updated my algo. Yes- my question though, is this the most efficient way to console log all 2 letter combinations in an array?

Comment: The most costly operation here is the log itself. So if you really want to log all the combinations, maybe then you should rather create a string with all the combinations and then print it once.